# SKLearn Ordinal Encoder with Pandas Dataframe - Accessing Columns with a variable

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, naivebayes

I'm trying to implement a categorical naive bayes classifier for some data I have in a dataframe.  My dataframe has 173 rows and 38 columns.  The columns represent categorical characteristics such as degree (ex. Mechanical Engineering) and type (ex. Master of Science).  There are many other columns and the number/variety of columns can change according to the dataframe (ex. a person may have multiple types of degrees in various subjects or none at all.  This is represented as degree1, degree2 ...).  Because of the variability of the columns, I want to send a variable to my dataframe when using ordinal encoder.  The problematic code is below:

```
def catEnconder(dataframe, *args):
    enc = OrdinalEncoder()
    enc_results = OrdinalEncoder()
    enc.fit([dataframe.columns.astype(str)])
    foo = "\'degree1\', \'type1\'"
    #dfOE = enc.transform(dataframe[['degree1', 'type1']].astype(str)) #This line works perfectly  
     dfOE = enc.transform(dataframe[[foo]].astype(str)) #This line fails. The error appears to be
     #"None of [Index([''degree1', 'type1''], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]" (although they definitely are)   
     dfOE = enc.transform(dataframe[dataframe.columns.astype(str)]) #This line fails. Error: 
     #Found unknown categories ['6D7', '6X1', ....] (these values represent departments that are within the dataframe)
     #Below works perfectly
     if args[0] == True:
         results = enc_results.fit_transform(dataframe[['DecisionDesc_en']].astype(str))
         return dfOE, results
     else:
         return dfOE
```

The lower half of the code works perfectly.  The shape of my results array is 173 x 1.  The issue is that I need my dfOE dataframe to be 173 x 38, but can't seem to get OrdinalEncoder to accept my dataframe inputs.  Any help on how to my columns as a variable to my dataframe (or OrdinalEncoder if that's where the problem is) would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Gary

Answer (score 2):

Ugh, please excuse my raging stupidity.  I guess there is part of me that likes to over-complicate things.  Easy solution was simply:

```
    dfOE = enc.fit_transform(dataframe.astype(str))
```

-Gary